# Java program that ask the user to enter the number of random values they wish to generate

Tags: random

Basically I need a program that ask the user to enter a number of random values that they wish to generate. Then the program has to generate the user specified number of random values. But each random number must be between 0 and 100. I need to have each number print and the value of the number in the console and at the end print the sum of the random values

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is not a code writing service. You should write your own homework code. When you do, and you run into problems getting it to work, you can post the code you've written here and ask a specific question about the problem you're having. Voting to close. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
  *
  * Beschreibung
  *
  * @version 1.0 vom 22.06.2013
  * @author 
  */ 
import java.io.*;

public class asd {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 
    System.out.println("How many numbers do you want to be generated?");
    String text = "";
    try{                                                
      text = in.readLine(); 
    }catch(IOException ioe){
    }

    int sum = 0, num=0;
    for (int i=0; i<Integer.parseInt(text); i++) {
      num = (int) (Math.random()*10000);
      System.out.println("Number "+(i+1)+": "+num);
      sum += num;
    } // end of for
    System.out.println("Sum of all: "+sum);
  } // end of main

} // end of class asd
```

you need to save this thing into "asd.java" and run it then.

Comment: getting a syntex error at: for (int i=0; i<Interger.parseInt(text); i++

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Java main function:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
int sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int r = (int)(Math.random() * 101)
    System.output.println(r);
    sum += r;
}
System.out.println("Sum = " + sum);
```